# I've been trying to run my seed script in prisma with nextJs and TS, and receiving the following error, is there any way to fix this?

Tags: typescript, next.js, prisma

in package.json, I've added the following lines:

```
"prisma": {
    "seed": "ts-node --compiler-options {\"module\":\"CommonJS\"} prisma/seed.ts"
 }
```

and when I run this: **npx prisma db seed**

OUTPUT:

An error occured while running the seed command:

```
Error: Command failed with ENOENT: ts-node --compiler-options {"module":"CommonJS"} prisma/seed.ts
spawn ts-node ENOENT
```

Answer (score 8):

This problem could be no `ts-node` installed. Please check your `package.json` file and see if there is any `ts-node` installed.

If not, just install `ts-node` with:

> npm i ts-node@<specific-version>

or add -D if you are in development mode:

> npm i ts-node@<specific-version> -D

In some situation, you may need to install Typescript as well:

> npm i typescript@<version-compatible-with-your-tsnode>

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is an issue with `ts-node` package. A workaround is to avoid ts-node altogether and create an NPM script to compile the file with tsc directly, execute with node, and clean up after it's been executed.

In your package.json you can add this script:

```
"db-seed": "tsc prisma/seed.ts && cat prisma/seed.js | node --input-type=\"commonjs\" && rm prisma/seed.js"
```

Your "seed" script would look like

```
"seed": "npm run db-seed"
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using prisma command like this `prisma migrate reset` but the currect way is using it with **yarn** `yarn prisma migrate reset`

Answer (score 0):

In package.json

```json
"scripts": {
    "db:seed": "ts-node --compiler-options '{\"module\":\"CommonJS\"}' prisma/seed.ts"
  },
```

Then execute it using package manager

```bash
 pnpm run db:seed
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I ran into this error message because I was using pnpx instead of npx. Once I switched to npx, it happened no more.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was using .env.local file to load the environment variables. So needed to install the 'dotenv-cli' to load the .local file after that I updated the package.json file with the following command:

```
"scripts":{
"db:seed": "dotenv -e .env.local -- ts-node prisma/seed.ts"
},
```

Then execute it using package manager

```
 pnpm db:seed
```